# How to write an email to a Professor to politely agree with his request?

Tags: email

Sometimes, my supervisor writes emails to ask whether we can cancel or reschedule our meetings, or request me other things. The way he writes emails is very polite. And I usually reply him by:

- Yes, sure!
- Yes, it's fine!

I wonder if these responses are considered polite?

How do I politely (but not really formally) respond to my Professors' requests?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it would be interesting to have to write a response that politely _disagrees_.

Comment: Yes that's fine

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend "That works for me." or "That sounds good."

I would say both of these are one "politeness-level" higher than the two phrases you mentioned. It's fine to use exclamation marks instead of periods here, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will up-vote it once I have enough reputation score :)

Comment: @TrungTa don't forget to accept an answer when you're satisfied that one answers your question well enough :)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest: "Thank you, I'm happy to rearrange."

Or, "Thank you, when's best for you?"

Or, "Not a problem, can we reconvene soon?"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your email - I'm happy to reschedule as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I like the simple, direct, but happy-sounding examples you use. As a professor, I am satisfied when students send replies such as those you have cited.